# Пагинация в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть метод:

```
        $user = RealUser::find($id)
        ->select(['id', 'login', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'sex', 'email', 'date_format(created, \'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i\') as created'])
        ->one();
    if (!$user) {
        return $this->redirect('index.php?r=users%2Findex');
    }

    $query = Address::find()->where(['user_id' => $id]);
    $countQuery = clone $query;
    $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery->count(), 'defaultPageSize' => self::ADDRESSES_ON_PAGE]);
    $pages->setPage($page);


    $addresses = $query->offset($page == 1 ? 0 :$pages->offset - self::ADDRESSES_ON_PAGE)
        ->limit($pages->limit)
        ->all();

    return $this->render('edit', ['user' => $user, 'addresses' => $addresses, 'sexes' => RealUser::getSexes(), 'pages' => $pages]);
```

Ну и в во вьюхе вывожу так:

```
echo LinkPager::widget([
'pagination' => $pages
```

]);

И вроде все работает за исключением того что во вьюхе неправильно подсвечивается активная ссылка, то есть я нахожусь на первой странице а подсвечивается вторая. Посмотрел исходный код в браузере, ссылка выглядит так:

```
<a href="/web/index.php?r=users%2Fedit&amp;id=1&amp;page=2" data-page="1">2</a>
```

Вот и что это за data-page и почему он не правильный?

Comment: Предположу, что проблема где-то здесь `$page == 1 ? 0 :$pages->offset - self::ADDRESSES_ON_PAGE` ..... если как в доках делать http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html - то норм?

Comment: без этого он на первой странице показывает начиная не с первой записи. Вообще как в документации описывается выглядит очень костыльно